# Drawing liquid inside a tilted test tube

Tags: tikz-pgf, technical-drawing

I am trying to modify the water inside the tilted test tube so that the water inside this tube flows up the tube like indicated by the yellow line.

Could anyone help me on this?

[image: Current output]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{polynom}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{flexisym}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\newenvironment{tightcenter}{
\setlength\topsep{0pt}
\setlength\parskip{0pt}
\begin{center}}{\end{center}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%TEST TUBE #1
\fill[color=gray!30] (-0.75,-3) arc (180:0:0.75 and 0.2) -- (0.75,-5) arc (0:-180:0.75);
\fill[color=black!70] (0,-3) ellipse (0.75 and .2);
%
\draw[thick] (0.75,0) -- (0.75,-5) arc (0:-180:0.75) -- (-0.75,0);
\draw[thick] (0,0) ellipse (0.75 and 0.2);
%
%
%TEST TUBE #2
\fill[color=gray!30][rotate around={+50.8:(-0.41,2.86)}] (-0.75,-3) arc (180:0:0.75 and 0.2) -- (0.75,-5) arc (0:-180:0.75);
\fill[color=black!70][rotate around={+50.8:(-0.41,2.86)}]  (0,-3) ellipse (0.75 and .2);
%
\draw[thick][rotate around={+50.8:(-0.41,2.86)}]  (0.75,0) -- (0.75,-5) arc (0:-180:0.75) -- (-0.75,0);
\draw[thick][rotate around={+50.8:(-0.41,2.86)}]  (0,0) ellipse (0.75 and 0.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want to be able to tilt your tube whatever angle and the surface automatically be drawn or is it just a one shot at this angle? Depending on your need, the answer would be different, the latter being easier.

Comment: Tilting the test tube in the angle shown (one shot) would be sufficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, so here's a very *ugly* way of doing it. I mean, no computation, only drawing on the fly. So it's not easily customizable, but since you asked for a one shot...

[image: drawing liquid into a tilted test tube]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{polynom}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{flexisym}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\newenvironment{tightcenter}{
\setlength\topsep{0pt}
\setlength\parskip{0pt}
\begin{center}}{\end{center}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    %TEST TUBE #1
    \fill[color=gray!30] (-0.75,-3) arc (180:0:0.75 and 0.2) -- (0.75,-5) arc (0:-180:0.75);
    \fill[color=black!70] (0,-3) ellipse (0.75 and .2);
    %
    \draw[thick] (0.75,0) -- (0.75,-5) arc (0:-180:0.75) -- (-0.75,0);
    \draw[thick] (0,0) ellipse (0.75 and 0.2);
    %
    %
\end{tikzpicture}%
\hspace*{2cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    %%TEST TUBE #2
    \fill[color=gray!30][rotate around={+50.8:(-0.41,2.86)}] (-0.75,-2.5) -- (0.75,-4.2) -- (0.75,-5) arc (0:-180:0.75) -- cycle;
    
    \fill[black!70] (3.52,-.75) arc (180:-180:1.15 and 0.25);
    \draw[thick][rotate around={+50.8:(-0.41,2.86)}]  (0.75,0) -- (0.75,-5) arc (0:-180:0.75) -- (-0.75,0);
    \draw[thick][rotate around={+50.8:(-0.41,2.86)}]  (0,0) ellipse (0.75 and 0.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: The tilted tube looks much emptier intuitively, and overlaying both in a graphics editor shows that it is indeed emptier.

Comment: You may be right. It could be edited in a minute with a bit of studying the code.