# How to draw a (standing up) test tube filled with water to height h

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, geometry

can someone help me with the latex code for a test tube that consists of a cylinder and a hemisphere and is filled with a liquid to height h? I am trying to write a solution for a question that asks for volume of the test tube. I am in Year 7 (1st year of secondary school). Thank you!

Comment: Maybe this? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/149255/47128

Answer (score -1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[color=gray!30] (-0.75,-3) arc (180:0:0.75 and 0.2) -- (0.75,-5) arc (0:-180:0.75);
    \fill[color=black!70] (0,-3) ellipse (0.75 and .2);
    \draw[thick] (0.75,0) -- (0.75,-5) arc (0:-180:0.75) -- (-0.75,0);
    \draw[thick] (0,0) ellipse (0.75 and 0.2);
    \draw[thick, <->] (1.2,-3) -- (1.2,-5.75);
    \node at (1.5,-4.375) {\(h\)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[color=gray!30] (-0.75,-3) arc (180:0:0.75 and 0.2) -- (0.75,-5) arc (0:-180:0.75);
    \fill[color=black!70] (0,-3) ellipse (0.75 and .2);
    \draw[thick] (0.75,0) -- (0.75,-5) arc (0:-180:0.75) -- (-0.75,0);
    \draw[thick] (0,0) ellipse (0.75 and 0.2);
    \draw[thick, <->] (1.2,-3) -- (1.2,-5);
    \node at (1.5,-4) {\(h\)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: test tube with liquid upto height h]

I have copied the code from [Drawing liquid inside a tilted test tube](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/628123/drawing-liquid-inside-a-tilted-test-tube).

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: because you should have provided a link to that in a comment, and not posted it here as a new solution.

Comment: How can I draw a figure that shows the hemisphere and cylinder in the test tube separately?

Comment: @riya draw another ellipse command at the bottom coordinates, and shift the hemisphere coordinates down. Add another ellipse command at the top of the hemisphere.

Comment: Can you please write the code for it?